# databricks with python can't use fs module AttributeError: module 'dbutils' has no attribute 'fs'

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I am using azure databricks for the first time to read some files and trying to use python with dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt")

But I get an error saying that dbutils doesn't have fs module. I was reading and say that all databricks come with dbutils already.

```
AttributeError: module 'dbutils' has no attribute 'fs'
```

[image]

if i do

```
print(dir(dbutils))
```

> ['Console', 'DBUtils', 'FileInfo', 'Iterable', 'ListConverter', 'MapConverter', 'MountInfo', 'NotebookExit', 'Py4JJavaError', 'SecretMetadata', 'SecretScope', 'WidgetsHandlerImpl', '**builtins**', '**cached**', '**doc**', '**file**', '**loader**', '**name**', '**package**', '**spec**', 'absolute_import', 'makeTensorboardManager', 'namedtuple', 'print_function', 'range', 'stderr', 'stdout', 'string_types', 'sys', 'zip']

i found that it suppose to have the library already install
https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dev-tools/dbutils.html#dbutils

Is there a magic trick? I wanted to check if I have a file is mounted if not mount it and unmount it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command `dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt")` is working fine in databricks, if the issue persists continue, please restart your cluster.

for the reference visit the following [link](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dbfs-databricks-file-system.html#dbfs)

Comment: @ Vladimir Nabokov, restarting the cluster is works. if not then terminate your cluster and then start again, might be it helps.

Comment: I got another solution to this problem. Do following steps:-

del(dbutils)
# detach the notebook from the cluster
# restart the cluster
# attach notebook to the cluster

Answer (score 9):

You will get this error "AttributeError: module 'dbutils' has no attribute 'fs'" if you *import dbutils* in your notebook. There is no need to do this import as the dbutils are available in the notebook on startup. print(dir(dbutils)) should return

> ['CredentialsHandler', 'FSHandler', 'LibraryHandler',
> 'NotebookHandler', 'PreviewHandler', 'SecretsHandler', '**call**',
> '**class**', '**delattr**', '**dict**', '**dir**', '**doc**',
> '**eq**', '**format**', '**ge**', '**getattr**', '**getattribute**',
> '**getstate**', '**gt**', '**hash**', '**init**', '**init_subclass**',
> '**le**', '**lt**', '**module**', '**ne**', '**new**', '**reduce**',
> '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**', '**setattr**', '**sizeof**', '**str**',
> '**subclasshook**', '**weakref**', 'entry_point', 'help', 'shell',
> 'widgets']

You don't need to restart the cluster, you can 'Clear State' from the clear tab in your workspace, or you can 'import pyspark.dbutils'.

Comment: thanks i will check that later,  in the mean time the admin restarted the cluster and worked.

Comment: Locally in Pycharm, "import pyspark.dbutils" doesn't work, module is not available.